# Record game is Invalid bug in AoM:EE

Tags: steam, technical-issues, age-of-mythology

I have the Age of Mythology: Extended Edition from Steam. I've downloaded some recorded games from [RTS Sanctuary](http://www.rts-sanctuary.com/Age-Of-Mythology/showforum=493) (link to the subforum, which is for AoM:EE replays only, technically). While some of them (specifically, [this](http://www.rts-sanctuary.com/Age-Of-Mythology/showtopic=244787) and [this](http://www.rts-sanctuary.com/Age-Of-Mythology/showtopic=244640)) to work, almost every other game can't be watched due to "Record game is Invalid" error.

The first game is quite recent (uploaded july 4th) and the second is from a month ago (june 3rd). Even the games in between don't seem to work, so it's most likely not a patch problem (unless someone is uploading some really old content recently - actually, most of them).

As I mentioned, I'm using the Steam version of AoM:EE with the Tales of the Dragon DLC. Some of the games I've downloaded and wasn't able to watch were played with Chinese gods, so it shouldn't be a Tales of the Dragon problem (i.e. they also recorded with a TotD game).

I run as ADM and, as I said, I was able to watch some games, so it's not a problem affecting everything.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the game with no success. I have also tried to run the game and recorded games in another computer (same steam account, same game download though) with no success either.

What is this problem and (how) can I fix it? Is there any other way I can watch these (or other high elo/tournament) games, as I'm interested to learn?

Comment: Your links don't work because you need to be logged in.

Comment: @Nzall Hm, forgot about that. Not sure if I should upload it as examples elsewhere, expect answerer to create an account or leave it as it, since it doesn't really affect the problem itself (some downloaded games, assumedly for the same patch I'm using, don't work, while others do).